Overpass Turbo - Search same values as conscription number in one address and street number in second address in the street
Hello,
in Czechia we have unique house numbering, Slovakia has too, but two numbers are everywhere where are named streets and all other buildings have address, but in Czechia have address usually main building in plot. Addresses have street name conscription number/street number.
I need to search same number values in address, which are occuring as conscription number in one address and as street number in second address in same street, for example, Jungmannova 35/29 and Jungmannova 29/19, where 29 is equivocal.
I only have so far search address with two same numbers, like 1/1.
/*
This query looks for nodes, ways and relations 
with the given key.
Choose your region and hit the Run button above!
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
nwr["addr:street"]["addr:conscriptionnumber"]["addr:streetnumber"]
(if: t["addr:street"]+t["addr:conscriptionnumber"] == t["addr:street"]+t["addr:streetnumber"])({{bbox}});
// print results
out geom;

How to build this?
Thanks.
I tried so search addresses which using first or second number is equivocal.
